# On what operating systems are the different functions of the select module in Python, like select(), poll(), epoll() available?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, io, network-programming

I was trying to use the `poll()` function on Windows when I realized that only the `select()` function is supported on windows, and I believe `poll()` is supported on Linux.
Could anyone help me out as to what functions of the select module are supported on what operating systems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the python `select` documentation:

> This module provides access to the select() and poll() functions
>   available in most operating systems, epoll() available on Linux 2.5+
>   and kqueue() available on most BSD. Note that on Windows, it only
>   works for sockets; on other operating systems, it also works for other
>   file types (in particular, on Unix, it works on pipes). It cannot be
>   used on regular files to determine whether a file has grown since it
>   was last read.

Comment: Thank you. I have actually read the documentation for select, but it was still unclear to me as to what functions a specific OS supports. Specifically, I wanted to know if Windows supports poll().

Comment: I would read this as it works on windows for sockets __only__!